# DataArray.mean does not retain coordinates

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray

**`DataArray.mean` does not retain a coordinate that depends on the dimension where the mean is applied to.**

NOTE: XLAT and XLONG are not time dependent; however, some netcdf files have a Time coordinate along these two.

I have this netcdf file wrfout_d03.nc wherein I open the file with:

`ds = xr.open_dataset('/Users/jacob/Desktop/wrfpy/wrfout_d03_may.nc')`

This then gives a DataSet object:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:                (Time: 193, bio_emissions_dimension_stag: 41, bottom_top: 50, bottom_top_stag: 51, klevs_for_dvel: 1, seed_dim_stag: 12, soil_layers_stag: 4, south_north: 115, south_north_stag: 116, west_east: 115, west_east_stag: 116)
Coordinates:
    XLAT                   (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 ...
    XLONG                  (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 ...
    XTIME                  (Time) datetime64[ns] ...
    XLAT_U                 (Time, south_north, west_east_stag) float32 ...
    XLONG_U                (Time, south_north, west_east_stag) float32 ...
    XLAT_V                 (Time, south_north_stag, west_east) float32 ...
    XLONG_V                (Time, south_north_stag, west_east) float32 ...
Dimensions without coordinates: Time, bio_emissions_dimension_stag, bottom_top, bottom_top_stag, klevs_for_dvel, seed_dim_stag, soil_layers_stag, south_north, south_north_stag, west_east, west_east_stag
Data variables:
datavars...
```

I then access the *PM2_5_DRY* variable with the following code:

```
pm25 = ds.PM2_5_DRY
```

The resulting object *pm25* has the following as its Dimensions and coordinates:

```
<xarray.DataArray 'PM2_5_DRY' (Time: 193, bottom_top: 50, south_north: 115, west_east: 115)>
[127621250 values with dtype=float32]
Coordinates:
    XLAT     (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 ...
    XLONG    (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 ...
    XTIME    (Time) datetime64[ns] ...
Dimensions without coordinates: Time, bottom_top, south_north, west_east
Attributes:
    FieldType:    104
    MemoryOrder:  XYZ
    description:  pm2.5 aerosol dry mass
    units:        ug m^-3
    stagger:
```

Then I manipulate the *pm25* object and get the mean in the *time* dimension through:

```
pm25_mean = pm25.mean(dim='Time', keep_attrs = True)
```

The resulting object is a DataArray but without the coordinates XLAT or XLON.

```
<xarray.DataArray 'PM2_5_DRY' (bottom_top: 50, south_north: 115, west_east: 115)>
array([[[14.73083   , 14.756626  , 14.796355  , ..., 20.325712  ,
         20.855696  , 21.381271  ],
        [14.651459  , 14.34477   , 14.371858  , ..., 18.00389   ,
         18.4109    , 21.337002  ],
        [14.59026   , 14.257076  , 14.293012  , ..., 17.391146  ,
         18.217058  , 20.882664  ],
        ...,
        [27.356459  , 27.21468   , 27.757051  , ...,  8.084272  ,
          8.010168  ,  7.989942  ],
        [27.185486  , 27.02623   , 27.776043  , ...,  7.944748  ,
          7.8795266 ,  7.8552976 ],
        [26.926008  , 27.724253  , 28.427626  , ...,  7.8269224 ,
          7.773637  ,  7.741844  ]],

Dimensions without coordinates: bottom_top, south_north, west_east
Attributes:
    FieldType:    104
    MemoryOrder:  XYZ
    description:  pm2.5 aerosol dry mass
    units:        ug m^-3
    stagger:
```

The following code to check gives:

```
pm25_mean.coords

Coordinates:
*empty*
```

I tried looking at the documentation for the mean function in xarray; however, I was not able to find any option to copy the coordinates from the previous object to the new one.

Any tips on how to go about this? I am thinking I need to access these coordinates from the file, and then combine them again. But I am not sure how to go through this process.

Also, does it have something to do with this?

```
XLAT     (Time, south_north, west_east) float32
```

XLAT is a multidimensional coordinate and it depends on Time as well. Since I got the mean in the Time dimension, the number of dimensions pm25 has was reduced to 3 instead of 4. Could this somehow have affected the coordinates as well?

I need the final object to have coordinates XLAT and XLONG since I will be visualising this.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to transform your coordinate variables from 3 to 2 dimensions.

```
d = xr.open_dataset('.../pm25_sample.nc')
d['XLAT'] = d.XLAT.mean(dim = 'Time')
d['XLONG'] = d.XLONG.mean(dim = 'Time')

d['PM2_5_DRY'].mean(dim = 'Time')

     ...,
    [ 0.03839084,  0.03837739,  0.03835952, ...,  0.03414929,
      0.03412561,  0.03410038],
    [ 0.03837854,  0.03836632,  0.03834687, ...,  0.03414606,
      0.0341224 ,  0.03409675],
    [ 0.03836945,  0.03835024,  0.03833132, ...,  0.03414177,
      0.03411727,  0.03409337]]], dtype=float32)
Coordinates:
    XLAT     (south_north, west_east) float32 14.086891 14.086907 ... 15.111996
    XLONG    (south_north, west_east) float32 120.49799 120.50717 ... 121.55791
Dimensions without coordinates: bottom_top, south_north, west_east
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this method since it's less complicated than my solution :D

Comment: This does not work as XLAT and XLON are not listed as variables in the DataSet.

Comment: @alberto_gar Did you try it? The example above works fine for me with the same data that you provided in the link.  Coordinates are considered a type of variable, and can be indexed the same way as a "regular" variable.

Comment: Sorry for that! I accidentally used the file I made without XLAT, and XLON. It seems to work properly now and this is a much easier solution to the issue. Thanks, @bwc ! :D

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no direct solution to this in xarray 
(As far as I know), but I found a solution via NCO.

This came from another post here. These are the steps I took to solve this issue.

First, the reason why XLAT and XLONG are not present in the final DataArray, is that these coordinates depend on time.

According to this thread : [Setting a coordinate constant in time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53428813/netcdf-set-variable-as-constant-in-time)

1. We must take the the NetCDF file and separate the variable (time-dependent) of interest.
2. We average out the XLAT and XLONG in time and place it in another nc file.
3. We append both files together to get the resulting time-independent XLAT and XLONG.

> ```
> ncks -v variable input.nc variable.nc
> ncwa -a Time -v XLAT,XLONG input.nc latlon.nc
> ncks -A latlon.nc variable.nc
> ```

This way, when accessing the file in xarray and computing the mean, we get the following DataArray:

```
<xarray.DataArray 'PM2_5_DRY' (bottom_top: 50, south_north: 115, west_east: 115)>
array([[[14.73083   , 14.756626  , 14.796355  , ..., 20.325712  ,
         20.855696  , 21.381271  ],
        [14.651459  , 14.34477   , 14.371858  , ..., 18.00389   ,
         18.4109    , 21.337002  ],
        [14.59026   , 14.257076  , 14.293012  , ..., 17.391146  ,
         18.217058  , 20.882664  ],
        ...,
Coordinates:
    XLAT     (south_north, west_east) float32 ...
    XLONG    (south_north, west_east) float32 ...
Dimensions without coordinates: bottom_top, south_north, west_east
```

Hope this also helps other people with the same issue!

Comment: Averaging coordinates in time sounds like a very bad plan :-) Did you actually use a moving domain in WRF?

Comment: No. I haven't used moving domains in my WRF configuration. But, the outputs still show that XLAt and XLONG still depend on time. I checked both of them and they seem to be static though time.